# How to migrate from one email provider to another?

Tags: email, migration, data

I've used my own domain with the email service of yandex.com. Now I want to migrate to another email service provider. I've chosen zoho.

1) How can I copy all my email from yandex to zoho? Or general, how can I copy all my email from a email service A to email service B?

2) I'm concerned about privacy and I'd like not to store my email on a server anymore and I'd better store them locally. At the same time it's vital for me to be able to access my email from a laptop and phone and tablet. So should I keep using IMAP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about unix or linux.

Comment: @cas, too late, I've already received an answer.

Comment: your question and its answer still doesn't belong here because it has nothing to do with unix or linux.  saying "nyah nyah nyah i got an answer anyway" just reflects badly on you.

Comment: @cas, yes. so what? who am I?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the backup you email on any email client (Thunderbird or evolution) its opensource, and after your backup you can switch from your provider to future Email provider (ZOHO).

Note in this you wont have your previous data to New ZOHO.

Comment: so I can upload zipped emails to Zoho or what?